# i want to push checked checkboxes and don't send unchecked checkboxes(pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can i push all checked checkboxes to array

Comment: What have you tried, where _specifically_ are you running into a problem? Please go read [ask]; a mere “I want” is not an actual question, you need to explain where exactly your _problem_ is with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass function reference to html and track it.

```
 <input type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange(event)">
```

JS:

```
function handleChange(e) {
    const {checked} = e.target;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is add an event listener to your new checkbox.
After `cell.appendChild(element1);`, you can add an event listener as follow:

```html
element1.addEventListner('click', () => {
  toggleThisNumber(0);
  // your other codes here
});
```